# Understanding Rails Guide association example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In the [Rails Guide for associations' has_many section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) is the following example:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

> The collection of join models can be managed via the API. For example, if you assign

```
physician.patients = patients
```

> new join models are created for newly associated objects, and if some are gone their rows are deleted."

I'd like to understand:

1) Where is the `physician.patients = patients` line occurring?
2) Who are the `patients` that are being assigned to `physician.patients`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `physician.patients = patients` can happen in a controller or a model.
2. `patients` is a list of `Patient` object that you can create before calling the above assignment.

Try this in the console:

```
> patient1 = Patient.create(...) # Pass appropriate parameters
> patient2 = Patient.create(...) # Pass appropriate parameters
> patients = [patient1, patient2]
> physician = Physician.create(...) # Pass appropriate parameters
> physician.patients = patients
> physician.patients.count
 => 2
```